# How do I manually deploy a C++ application on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, gtk, gtkmm

I have built a C++ application based on gtkmm (The C++ language wrapper for GTK+). I used Code Blocks to build the application. I want to know what to include in an installation package (such as one created by NSIS). For example, how do I structure the directories of the installed package (i.e. where are the .dlls included, and what else do I need in order to let me application run successfully on another PC without the dependencies installed)? I am new to deployment, and would really appreciate references and/or tutorials for an amateur in this area. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to include your compilers runtime libraries + any other libraries you use (directly or indirectly).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not what you mean by including a library. Can you be more specific? Where do I include it and what exactly is included? Thanks

Comment: I hope this is more clear: 1) your compiler has libraries (usually .so or .dll files) that implement the standard library as well as various helper functions the compiler relies on. You need to include these with your program or it will not run. 2) if you use any other libraries (like, say, `boost`, `sfml`, `qt` or whatever) then you also need to include those with your program. 3) if some of the libraries you use *also* use other libraries, then you also need to include the files from those other libraries in order for the lib you directly use to function (and hence your app to function).

Comment: @JesperJuhl That makes more sense, thanks. So in theory if I could determine all the dependencies of my project, I could include all their .dll or .so files in the same directory as the generated .exe file?

Comment: There's no "in theory" about that. You absolutely *can* determine that. There are tools that will show you what some executable or library is linked with - like `ldd` on Linux (and other UNIX platforms) and other OSs have similar tools.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks! Your comment really helped. I have MSYS2 installed but ldd was only returning windows dlls for some reason. I ended up using pestudio as a workaround to include the right .dlls, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.